# iOS/Cocos2d - Circle detection during finger movement

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-x

I am working on a cocos2d-x based game on iOS platform.

In my game, I need to detect circular gesture over the bounding box of a particular sprite.
I have the solution to detect the circle when a touch event is ended at 
http://blog.federicomestrone.com/2012/01/31/creating-custom-gesture-recognisers-for-ios/

But, it is required that the circle should be detected during onTouchMove and not onTouchEnded.
Also, I need to know the direction in which circle is being created, i.e. clockwise or anti-clockwise. and change of direction during finger move.
Another requirement is to count the number of circles completed while the finger is moving.

Need some help with this kind of circle gesture detection.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

During a touch move event you can determine the angle from the center of the sprite to the touch position using the following (pseudocode):

```
angle = atan2(touch.y - spriteCenter.y, touch.x - spriteCenter.x);
```

Then find the angular offset since the last measurement and add it to a running tally:

```
angleOffset = atan2(sin(angle-lastAngle), cos(angle-lastAngle));
angleRotated += angleOffset;
```

|angleRotated| will measure how many revolutions were made and in which direction they occurred.

You may also want to take the distance between the touch and the sprite into consideration to ensure the shape is circle-like.